# In how many ways can $10$ letters be placed in $10$ addressed envelope such that exactly $9$ letters are in correct envelope?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

I have one problem which goes like this: "**In how many ways can $10$ letters be placed in $10$ addressed envelope such that exactly $9$ letters are in correct envelope?**"

If I understand the problem correctly this is similar to counting [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) with exactly $r$ matches,I don't know how to do it,please help.

Comment: Zero? The tenth letter should go into the correct envelope as well.

Comment: I don't have the answer/solution for this one.

Comment: There is less to this problem than meets the eye.

Comment: @André Nicolas:Pardon,what exactly do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many fixed points in a permutation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/how-many-fixed-points-in-a-permutation)

Comment: @Tretwick , André probably wants you to think about what exactly the question is asking more deeply. If 9 letters are in the correct envelope, how many letters are in incorrect envelopes?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17320/derivation-of-the-partial-derangement-rencontres-numbers-formula

Comment: @Aryabhata I thought so too, but this question is more like a puzzle :-)

Comment: @Srivatsan: I was going by the title and was addressing the general question.

Comment: It has already been solved by @Srivatsan Narayanan.  Can exactly $9$ be in the right envelope? No, because there is only one letter left over, and the right envelope for that letter.

Comment: Something less abstract than envelopes and letters. Ten married couples. All $20$ people are dancing, in pairs. Could *exactly* $9$ women be dancing with their husbands? Who is left over for the $10$th woman to dance with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nine letters go into the correct envelopes, what can you say about the remaining 1 letter?

The following is not necessary for solving this problem, but I am adding it since you mentioned derangements and number of permutations with exactly $k$ matches (aka fixed points).  The more general problem is to find the number of permutations with exactly $k$ fixed points. The solution for this is described in [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).

Comment: It has to go the correct envelope.

Comment: Yes. So, the answer is...

Comment: $0$,thanks a lot for your inputs :-)