# If n friends go to a diner, and take a hat randomly...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, derangements, eulers-number-e

If n friends go to a diner, and when leaving, each of them take a hat randomly, what is the probability of "nobody gets his original hat"?
My book says it goes to 1/e, but I don't have more explanation... 
Can you help me?

Comment: Start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Some related posts:
[What is the probability that no letter is in its proper envelope?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643434),
[Why is the Derangement Probability so Close to $\frac{1}{e}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399500),
[Number of permutations of $n$ elements where no number $i$ is in position $i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14666),
[How many fixed points in a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22537).

Answer (score 1):

On one hand from inclusion-exclusion principle it follows, that the number of ways to distribute the hats in a way, that nobody gets the original one is $!n := n! \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$.

On the other hand $e^x = \sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}$.

Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{!n}{n!} = \frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

It will be  $P(E)=\frac{D_n}{n!}$  where $ D_n $ is dearangement of n objects at n places .
For more about dearangement you can listen to podcast
 https://podcasts.google.com?feed=aHR0cHM6Ly9hbmNob3IuZm0vcy9lZjA0NTQ4L3BvZGNhc3QvcnNz&episode=NTU3YmQyZTQtYjVlOC00MTlkLTliN2UtNjhlYjU5MzFiNGIw
Or.  Listen to inclusion and exclusion principle , Dearrangement And Number of onto functions. on TuneIn http://tun.in/tjwNzd

And as $n \rightarrow \infty \,\,,\frac{D_n}{n!}=\frac{1}{e}$