# Gift exchange problem

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the General Expression For Probability of a Failed Gift Exchange Draw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/whats-the-general-expression-for-probability-of-a-failed-gift-exchange-draw)

4 couples are doing a gift exchange. Names are drawn randomly. Everyone gets a gift, but no one is allowed to pick either themself or their spouse. How many successful arrangements are there?

Comment: I think one of the answers at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85470/secret-santa-problem covers this.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/whats-the-general-expression-for-probability-of-a-failed-gift-exchange-draw

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85559/12042) gives the numerical value as $4752$; [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/73364/12042) gives the general formula.

Comment: Is there a reason why neither of you voted to close as duplicate?

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28x%5E2-4x%2B2%29%5E4e%5E%28-x%29+for+x%3D0..infinity) for the computation according to the general formula Brian linked to. I'm voting to close as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @joriki, speaking only for myself, I was too rushed to read the other questions closely enough to be certain there is a duplication. But if you are convinced, pick one, vote to close, and I'll go along with you.