# Laguerre polynomials and inclusion-exclusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, special-functions, inclusion-exclusion

Does anyone know a reference for the solution of the 
generalized derangement problem via Laguerre polynomials?
The [Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations) says that this is an application
of inclusion-exclusion, but I don't see how.

This formula was used by joriki in a [nice MSE answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/whats-the-general-expression-for-probability-of-a-failed-gift-exchange-draw).

The article below solves the generalized derangement problem with
inclusion-exclusion, but without Laguerre polynomials.

> **Reference:**  Finn F. Knudsen and Ivar Skau, "On the Asymptotic Solution of a Card-Matching Problem", *Mathematics Magazine 69* (1996), 190-197.

Comment: There's a related article in a recent issue of *Mathematics Magazine* that may interest you.  See the Kayll reference in my [blog post here](http://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/derangements2/).

Comment: @Mike Thanks for this, it looks like an interesting paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is due to

> J. Gillis and S.Even, "*Derangements and Laguerre polynomials*", Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, Volume 79 / Issue 01, pp 135 - 143.

Link to the article: [DOI:10.1017/S0305004100052154](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100052154)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.

Comment: I added this as a reference in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: The paper is placed in a wider context in [this paper](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/rookp.pdf) on rook polynomials.