# Derangements with repetitive numbers

Tags: probability, card-games, derangements

I have a very simple problem.

Lets assume that I have a well shuffled deck of 52 cards. I start drawing the top card always and when the card matches its rank I lose. J=11 Q=12 K=13.

If there were only 13 cards I could easily use the $\ \frac{!n}{n!}$ for derangements in order to solve this.
The problem is that there are 52 cards so when I pass 13 I start from 1 again so I don't know what is the probability to win.
Example of the game

> 1st card: 4 - Continue
>   2nd Card: A - continue
>   3rd Card: K - Continue
>   4th Card: K - Continue
>   5th Card: 6 - Continue
>   6th Card: 9 - Continue
>   7th Card: 10 - Continue
>   8th Card: A - Continue
>   9th Card: J - Continue
>   10th Card: 3 - Continue
>   11th Card: 2 - Continue
>   12th Card: 8 - Continue
>   13th Card: A - Continue
>   1st card: 5 - Continue
>   **2nd Card 2 LOSE**

So actually I have to count from 1 to 13 4 times and if I draw all 52 cards then I win. What's the probability?

Comment: See also the answers at [this duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495991).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is given in [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations) on generalized derangements. The number of permutations of $52$ cards with $4$ copies each of $13$ ranks that leave none of the ranks in place is

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty (4!\cdot L_4(x))^{13}\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx
=\int_0^\infty\left(x^4-16x^3+72x^2-96x+24\right)^{13}\mathrm e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx
\\\\\\
=&1309302175551177162931045000259922525308763433362019257020678406144
\end{align}
$$

([computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20%284!%20Laguerre%20%5B4,x%5D%29%5E13%20exp%28-x%29%20for%20x=0..infinity)), where $L_4(x)$ is the fourth [Laguerre polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials). Since there are

$$
52!=80658175170943878571660636856403766975289505440883277824000000000000
$$

permutations of the cards in all, your chances of winning are

$$
\frac{1309302175551177162931045000259922525308763433362019257020678406144}{80658175170943878571660636856403766975289505440883277824000000000000}
$$

$$
=\frac{4610507544750288132457667562311567997623087869}{284025438982318025793544200005777916187500000000}
$$

$$
\approx0.0162\;.
$$

See also [What's the General Expression For Probability of a Failed Gift Exchange Draw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73341), [Laguerre polynomials and inclusion-exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89966) and [Counting some special derangements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94415).

Comment: Thank joriki this is extremely helpful

Comment: I love that you have written out the numerator and denominator entirely as integers and not expressions.  It is hauntingly beautiful in a way.