# The probability of a match in a card game

Tags: probability

I found the following problem in the book Understanding Probability:

An ordinary deck of 52 cards is thoroughly shuffled. The dealer turns over the cards one at a time, counting as he goes ``ace, two, three, $\ldots$ , king, ace, two, $\ldots$," and so on, so that the dealer ends up calling out the thirteen ranks four times each. A match occurs if the card that comes up matches the rank called out by the dealer as he turns it over.

The author states that the inclusion-exclusion rule can be used to find  the value 0.9838 for the probability of at least one match.  I could not reproduce this result.

As pointed by Joriki, a derivation of this result is given in

[Derangements with repetitive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247224/derangements-with-repetitive-numbers)

This quite complicated derivation is based on an integral representation involving  a Laguerre polynomial of degree four.  However, for the specific example, you would expect that a a direct application of the inclusion-exclusion formula  must be possible.

Comment: Have you read related problems like the birthday paradox ?